# Relative layout change through java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I went through several links yet i am not able to find if it is possible to set other attributes of relative layout, like android:gravity,android:orientation through java code.
I want to change the positions of the some of the views through java code and not through xml.

e.g, i want to set these attributes through java code for a particular view. android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical"

how can i do so? please help.

Comment: Gravity isn't available within a relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

as Daan said you can use Layout params for relative layout in android

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.alignWithParent = true;
params.bottomMargin = 5;
params.height = 50;
params.leftMargin = 50;
```

But as you said you want to set following attributes for particular view, you cannot assign these attributes to RelativeLayout as these are belongs to LinearLayout and other views

```
android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical"
```

For setting gravity for any view please follow the code

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

You cannot set Orientation of any view.. instead you can set orientation to LinearLayout

like this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Within a relative layout you have to use other layout params:
[Layout params within relative layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)